# How can we get the value from the async Action Method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `async` method like

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> AddTwoIntegers(int param1, int param2)
{         
   var result = await (param1 + param2);
   return Json(new {finalValue: result}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)            
}
```

Now in another `Action Method` i am calling this function

```
public ActionResult SomeFunction(string userSettingsViewModel)
{          
      Task<JsonResult> jsonData = this.AddTwoIntegers(5,10);          

      jsonData.ContinueWith(task =>
      {
           JsonResult result = task.Result;
           if (result.Data.ToString() == "") {
                var data = result.Data;
           }            
      });

      // I want to retrieve the value returned and use that value in some operation.

      return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How can i get the returned value from the `Action Result`.

Comment: `await (param1 + param2);` Cool!

Comment: Does this even compile? You can't await an `int`... `await (param1 + param2)`

Comment: my use case is different for understanding i have given a sample code. What i actually need is i want to access the value in another action method. But its just jumping from there. I am not obtaining the value

Comment: It is better to show what you have done. Because the code written there with `async` and `await` can be avoided. You can't use it like that.

Comment: @lnanikian yah its all about changing passwords and that stuff. I can't write it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the method to return `Task<ActionResult>` and mark it as `async`, then await the result from `AddTwoIntegers()`...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeFunction(string userSettingsViewModel)
{          

    JsonResult result = await this.AddTwoIntegers(5, 10);  
    var jsonData = result.data;

    // ...

    return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

For completeness, the sample method should look something like this...

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<JsonResult> AddTwoIntegers(int param1, int param2)
{         
   var result = param1 + param2;
   return Task.FromResult(Json(new {finalValue: result}, 
                               JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
JsonResult = await AddTwoIntegers(5,10);
```

Check [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to declare the variable who store your result outside the operation. And then use the variable.

Task jsonData = this.AddTwoIntegers(5,10);

```
   Type data = null; //Note that I put Type because I don't know your type for result.Data 
  jsonData.ContinueWith(task =>
  {
       JsonResult result = task.Result;
       if (result.Data.ToString() == "") {
             data = result.Data;
       }            
  });

  // I want to retrieve the value returned and use that value in some operation.
  //Now you can use your variable data here!!
  return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

Comment: my question is can i get the addition of the two values in to that. As i am returning json resuslt. How can i access the return the integer value